# Weighted sum of RBF kernels with different length scales

Tags: gaussian-process, kernel-trick, rbf-kernel

When applying Gaussian Processes to applied problems, the choice of length-scale parameter parameter for the radial basis function (RBF, ie Gaussian) kernel makes a big difference. In practice, I have found that instead of using a single length-scale parameter, then optimizing it via cross-validation, it often works well to use the weighted sum of RBF kernels, each with their own length-scale. In other words, I estimate the mean pairwise-distance `gamma_0` among training points, then use the following sum-of-kernels:

`sklearn.gaussian_process.kernels.RBF(length_scale=gamma_0) + sklearn.gaussian_process.kernels.RBF(length_scale=0.1*gamma_0) + sklearn.gaussian_process.kernels.RBF(length_scale=10.*gamma_0)`

Is there a term for this type of approach in the academic literature? Furthermore, is there an intuition for why this seems to work well? I've used equal weights of 1 when summing these kernels, but are there better principles for choosing these weights without using cross-validation? If one takes the limit of summing a large number K of these kernels instead of three, and chooses the weights in a particular way, do we simply recover some other (eg linear) kernel?

Comment: In terms of cross-validation, a weighted sum of RBF kernels is always going to perform better than a single RBF kernel because the weighted sum is more flexible. A single RBF kernel can always be written as a weighted sum of RBF kernels. Whenever you consider a more flexible model, you have to be wary of overfitting.

Comment: Sorry, I should be more specific. A weighted sum of RBF kernels will always have better training accuracy. I assume test accuracy will increase as the number of summands increases, but it will begin to deteriorate when there are too many summands due to overfitting.

Comment: @JLinsta - might want to expand that into an answer!

Comment: @JLinsta - I agree that if one tunes the weights, the weighted sum can always attain better training accuracy. But this is not guaranteed if one restricts to equal weights, so it's a bit surprising when the above equal-weighted form improves accuracy.